# Opening another fxml on top as pop up

Tags: java, javafx, java-8

I currently use this code to change scenes in my JFX program:

```
public void addTaskFunction (ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
        Parent addTaskParent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/LogIn/AddDataToTaskManager.fxml"));
        Scene addTaskScene = new Scene(addTaskParent);
        Stage appStage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        appStage.setScene(addTaskScene);
        appStage.setResizable(true);
        appStage.show();
    }
```

Using this code closes the previous stage and opens a new one on top. How can I make it so the previous stage does not close and this **AddDataToTaskMaager.fxml** opens on top of **TaskManager.fxml**

Thank you

Comment: you need a new Stage or a Popup(if you want a popup...) instead of setting new content to the stage that is currently displayed. Problem here ->  "Stage appStage = (Stage) ((Node) "event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow(); appStage.setScene(addTaskScene);"

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code with tips from @kai

```
public void addTaskFunction (ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
        Parent addTaskParent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/LogIn/AddDataToTaskManager.fxml"));
        Scene addTaskScene = new Scene(addTaskParent);
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setTitle("Thank You");
        stage.setScene(addTaskScene);
        stage.show();
    }
```

Comment: optional: you could also add: stage.initOwner(appStage) if you want the new Stage to be a Child of the appStage.